# Replace reqirep directive in HAProxy 2.2.25

Tags: haproxy

I've upgraded from an old version of HAProxy to the 2.2.25.
In the configuration file I have this line:

```
reqirep Destination:\ https(.*) Destination:\ http\\1
```

With 2.2.25, I get this error:

```
Errors found while starting haproxy
[NOTICE] 064/171311 (1035) : haproxy version is 2.2.25-50b5f5d
[ALERT] 064/171311 (1035) : parsing [/var/etc/haproxy_test/haproxy.cfg:102] : The 'reqirep' directive is not supported anymore since HAProxy 2.1. Use 'http-request replace-header' instead.
[ALERT] 064/171311 (1035) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /var/etc/haproxy_test/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 064/171311 (1035) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

What is the new syntax in 2.2.25?

I had a look to `http-request replace-header` but it doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent configuration would be

```
http-request replace-header Destination (?i)https(.*) http\1
```

Please see https://docs.haproxy.org/2.2/configuration.html#http-request%20replace-header for the complete documentation of the `http-request replace-header` rule.

Note that all `http-request` rules are evaluated in the strict order they are stated in the configuration file. This order may differ from the order in which the rules where evaluated before with the `req*` rules.

Also note that in the search regex, I used an inline modifier to turn on case-insensitive matching. This makes the query equivalent to your `reqirep` rule which also uses case-insensitive matching. By default, `http-request replace-header` matches case-sensitive (i.e. equivalent to `reqrep`).

Finally, the double backslash in `\\1` in your original configuration is odd. I assume this is an artifact of your quoting and/or templating language. When using your actual original statement, your `Destination` header would be replaced with the literal `http\1` value rather than inserting the remainder of the header value matched in the regex.